# Some basic definitions on the ring $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, divisibility

Let $n\in\mathbb{N}^*$ be a composite number. So $\mathbb{Z}_n[x]$ is not an integral domain.

What are the definitions of divisible, common factor, maximal common factor, coprime, modular arithmetic and elimination ?

Comment: If the regular definitions still make sense, I'd say use those. Otherwise, maybe have a think about whether the concept even makes sense in the first place.

Comment: Could you please provide some sources for the definitions? I can't find the authoritative source.

Comment: As $Z_n$ isn’t a unique factorization domain, those wouldn’t be very good notions, for example, in $Z_6$ $4=2 \cdot 2= 4 \cdot 4 = 2 \cdot 5$